# Child born in Jamaica to Pakistani Parents

Tags: pakistani-citizens, jamaica, jamaican-citizens

We are expecting to give birth in Jamaica and parents are Pakistani.

As Pakistan has no diplomatic mission in Jamaica, what would be the next steps for us to get right travel documents (for example Passport)

Also can a child get Jamaican Citizenship (even if both parents are non Jamaicans)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

According to section 3B(1)(b) of the [constitution of Jamaica](https://www.constituteproject.org/constitution/Jamaica_2011.pdf), anyone born in Jamaica is automatically a Jamaican citizen at birth, except children born to foreign diplomats with diplomatic immunity.

The embassy of Pakistan in Washington, DC in the United States has jurisdiction over Jamaica. See the [handbook for overseas Pakistanis](https://mofa.gov.pk/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/Handbook_for_Overseas_Pakistanis.pdf) and [this archived page](https://web.archive.org/web/20230104095458/https://embassyofpakistanusa.org/jurisdiction/) from the embassy of Pakistan in Washington. You should contact them about getting the child a Pakistani passport.